# Gmail django sending

Tags: django

Today, looking at a page about django recommendations, I got the concept of a fat model and skinny views, so I had a doubt if what it was doing was good or not and if it could be applied to a model and how?

```
 def EnvioGmail(self,Nombre,gmail):
        context = {"Gmail":gmail,"Nombre":Nombre}
        template = get_template("Correo.html")

        content = template.render(context)#Renderisamos la plantilla con el contexto
        email = EmailMultiAlternatives(#Este sirve para enviar muchos correos como html
                "Registro exitoso",
                "",
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                [gmail]
            )

        email.attach_alternative(content,"text/html")#Es para atajar el email y darle mas datos como el contenido y comos se mostrara
        email.send()
                  
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        Formmain = Usuarios(request.POST)
       
        if Formmain.is_valid():          
            Usuario = Formmain.cleaned_data["nombre"]
            Gmail = Formmain.cleaned_data["gmail"]#Aqui extraemos el gmail del objeto Formulario
            self.EnvioGmail(Usuario,Gmail)            
            Formmain.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/Informacion/")
        else:
            Mensaje ="Porfavor revisa tus datos"
            return render(request,"Base.html",{"Mensaje":Mensaje,"Formulario":Usuarios})
```

I hope someone can help me, I'm still learning many things about django.